# __attribute__((noinline)) constant variable attribute equivalent in gcc

Tags: c, gcc, keil

Keil compiler has a constant variable attribute that prevents the compiler from making any use of a constant data value for optimization purposes, without affecting its placement in the object. "http://www.keil.com/support/man/docs/armccref/armccref_cjaifcbj.htm". Does any version gcc have such an option?

Comment: Is this different from `const volatile`?

Comment: Yes, it is actually. const volatile avoids optimization totally. However __attribute__((noinline)) allows some level of optimization.